Why am I getting Invalid Grant error while using Refresh Token to Generate Access Token using Dropbox Sign .NET SDK
I am using the following Dropbox Sign .NET SDK code in my project to generate Dropbox Sign Access token using previously saved Refresh token.
    public async Task<TokenResponse> GetRefreshToken(TokenResponse tokenResponse)
    {
        TokenResponse tokenResponse2 = new TokenResponse();
        string errorlog = ConfigurationManager2.AppSettings("ErrorLog");

        var config = new Configuration();
        var oAuthApi = new OAuthApi(config);
       
        try
        {
            var data = new OAuthTokenRefreshRequest(refreshToken: tokenResponse.RefreshToken);

            var result = await oAuthApi.OauthTokenRefreshAsync(data);
            if (result != null)
            {
                tokenResponse2.Expires = result.ExpiresIn;
                tokenResponse2.AcquireTime = DateTime.Now;
                tokenResponse2.AccessToken = result.AccessToken;
                tokenResponse2.RefreshToken = result.RefreshToken; 
                tokenResponse2.AcquireTime = DateTime.UtcNow;                  
            }               

            return tokenResponse2;
        }            
        catch (ApiException ex)
        {                
                File.AppendAllText(errorlog, "\r\n\r\n" + "nGetRefreshToken: - Error");
                File.AppendAllText(errorlog, "\r\nException when calling Dropbox Sign API: " + ex.Message);
                File.AppendAllText(errorlog, "\r\nStatus Code: " + ex.ErrorCode);
                File.AppendAllText(errorlog, "\r\nStack Trace: " +  ex.StackTrace);
         
        throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(errorlog, "\r\nGetRefreshToken - Error");
            File.AppendAllText(errorlog, "\r\n" + ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return tokenResponse;
    }

I am getting the following Error Message and Stack Trace.
Error converting value "invalid_grant" to type 'Dropbox.Sign.Model.ErrorResponseError'. Path 'error', line 1, position 24.
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
.....
.....
at SGCloudMigration.Business.DropboxSignUtility.GetRefreshToken(TokenResponse tokenResponse, String relationshipname) in D:\SG Cloud Migration\SGCloudMigration.Business.Core\DropboxSignUtility.cs:line 364
Please suggest.
Thanks!

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-Sign-API/Invalid-Grant-whlie-generating-Access-Token-using-saved-Refresh/td-p/762746 ]
